# How to properly stop QThread run() function?

Tags: multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qml, qt5

I have one thread, producer and class consumer. Consumer is registered in QML, and producer is connected with signals to consumer. Producer send data to consumer, so consumer can update the model and GUI.

Code looks something like this:

Main function:

```
    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
        Producer producer;
        Consumer consumer;

    /* Connect signals between producer and consumer */
    ...
    ...

       QQuickView view;

        /* Set root context */
        QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
        producer.start();

        ctxt->setContextProperty("consumer", &consumer);
        /*Connect signals between consumer and QML*/
        ...
        view.show();

        return app.exec();
}
```

Producer:

```
class Producer : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void run()
    {
     while(true) {
            if (someFlag == true)
            {
                // do some work
                // emit signal with data to consumer
            }
     }
   }
signals:
// Signals for sending data
};
```

**The question** is how to properly stop thread Producer when exit in application is pressed?

Comment: Think about migrating to C++11 `std::thread`, then we won't need to read the `QThread`'s documentation to find out.

Comment: There is one way to properly stop any function - use `return`

Comment: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: I have tried with std::thread, but someone told me to use Qthread, hmm.. 
I am not sure which one to use, but for now QThread works fine, so does solution recommended by @Kevin Kramer in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `while(true)` check for a "should end" condition, e.g. `isInterruptionRequested()`.

Then, in `main()`, before returning, you tell the thread to stop, e.g. with `QThread::requestInterruption` and then `wait` on the thread

```
view.show();

const int ret = app.exec();

producer.requestInterruption();
producer.wait();

return ret;
```

Comment: As simple as that. I don't know is this the best approach, but it works just fine in this case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion:

My way of doing is, Register the windows close event and do any sort of cleaning activities in it.

pseudo code below. try to fit it in your application.

### Close filter event:

```
class CloseEventFilter : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     CloseEventFilter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

protected: 
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
     {
          if (event->type() == QEvent::Close)
          { 
              // Destroy your thread here.
                 producer->exit();//Make your thread available 
               //... may be global....producer is derived from QThread.
          }

          return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event)
     }
}
};
```

### Registering to windows

```
//Registering window
QGuiApplication *app = new QGuiApplication(argc,argv);
QWindow* qtwindow = new QWindow();
CloseEventFilter *closeFilter = new CloseEventFilter(window);
qtwindow >installEventFilter(closeFilter);
```

**Why thread exit funtion** (from documentation)

void QThread::exit(int returnCode = 0)

Tells the thread's event loop to exit with a return code.

After calling this function, the thread leaves the event loop and returns from the call to QEventLoop::exec(). The QEventLoop::exec() function returns returnCode.

By convention, a returnCode of 0 means success, any non-zero value indicates an error.

Note that unlike the C library function of the same name, this function does return to the caller -- it is event processing that stops.

No QEventLoops will be started anymore in this thread until QThread::exec() has been called again. If the eventloop in QThread::exec() is not running then the next call to QThread::exec() will also return immediately.

See also quit() and QEventLoop.

Comment: `QThread::exit()` isn't sufficient in this case as the thread here does not run an event loop but a custom processing loop.

Comment: Ok. When custom process is done, can we call "emit finished()" signal?

Comment: That happens automatically once the `run()` ends.
`QThread::started()` and `QThread::finished()` are handled by the base implementation before and after `run()` respectively

Comment: OK. Thanks. Understood.

Answer (score 0):

The `while (true) if (someFlag)` loop will peg the CPU at 100% when there's no work to be done. You don't want that!

Alas, there's no need to make the `Producer` be a `QThread`. It can be a plain old `QObject`. There are different ways of doing it.

You can use a zero-duration timer to keep the event loop active in the thread:

```
class Producer : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) override {
    if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId()) 
      doWorkChunk();
  }
  void doWorkChunk() {
    ...
    emit hasData(...);
  }
public:
  Producer(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent} {
    connect(this, &Producer::start, this, [this]{ m_timer.start(this, 0); });
    connect(this, &Producer::stop, this, [this]{ m_timer.stop(); });
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void start();
  Q_SIGNAL void stop();
  Q_SIGNAL void hasData(const DataType &);
};
```

Instead of setting/clearing the flag, call `start()` and `stop()`. Then you can move the producer to any thread and it will work just fine, doing the right thing on exit (wrapping things up *cleanly*):

```
class Thread : public QThread {
  using QThread::run;
public:
  ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
  Producer producer;
  Thread thread; // must come after producer above, the order has meaning!
  producer.moveToThread(&thread);
  thread.start();
  return app.exec();
}
```

You can use the Qt Concurrent framework, too:

```
class Producer : public QObject {
{
  Q_OBJECT
  volatile bool m_active = false;
  void doWorkChunk() {
    ...
    emit hasData();
  }
  void doWork() {
    while (m_active) doWorkChunk();
  }
public:
  using QObject::QObject;
  ~Producer() { stop(); }
  void start() {
    m_active = true;
    QtConcurrent::run(this, &Producer::doWork);
  }
  void stop() {
    m_active = false;
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void hasData(const DataType &);
};
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are usnig Q_SIGNAL instead of the common syntax of having a signals section?
Or a QBasicTimer instead of a normal QTimer? Or even just a `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()? in `start()` and at the end of `doWorkChunk()` if there is more work?

Comment: Also I don't think the order of creation of Producer and Thread matters.

Comment: The "common" syntax of having a signals section is no more common than using `Q_SIGNAL` :) Both are equally supported by moc, and - more importantly - they let you logically group your method declarations. Just because something is a signal doesn't necessarily make it belong with other signals. Code is for humans to easily comprehend first and foremost.

Comment: The order of creation of Producer and Thread does matter because it defines the reverse order of destruction. It's undefined behavior to destruct an object in use in another thread. The thread must be destructed first, the Producer then has a null `thread()` and can be destroyed from any thread.

Comment: A `QTimer` is no more "normal" than a `QBasicTimer`. `QTimer` is more heavyweight because it's a yet another `QObject`. If you're within a `QObject`, you use a `QBasicTimer`. If you're outside a `QObject`, or want a timer decoupled from the object, use `QTimer`.

Comment: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` does a run-time string lookup. Using it is premature pessimization compared to using a signal and the new connect syntax. The new syntax also does a run-time lookup, but it's a single-time lookup, and it compares method pointers, not strings.

Comment: Good point about the method lookup of invokeMethod, a connect lookup only happens once.
I would still go for a QTimer, less verbose than manual event handling.
And also would go for the standard syntax for declaring signals for readability by other Qt developers

Comment: Again, the `Q_SIGNAL` syntax **is standard**. That you haven't heard of it before is solely because you didn't read the documentation, only Qt Creator templates or some examples that derive from such templates.

Comment: I am aware of the macro, just saying that it is not commonly used.
Almost every class one will come across uses sections for signals and slots, that's what I meant with standard.